# Passing prop from father to child modal component using bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Having father component -

```
<b-nav-item @click="loginModalShow = !loginModalShow">Show</b-nav-item>
<LoginModal :loginShow="loginModalShow"/>

export default {
data () {
  return {
    loginModalShow: false,
  }
}
```

Having child component -

```
<b-modal
  ref="LoginModal"
  v-model="showModal"
/>

export default {
props:['loginShow'],
data () {
  return {
    showModal: this.loginShow,
  }
 }
}
```

My problem is when I click the `b-nav-item Show`, the modal doesn't open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is updating a property on the LoginModal and expecting the data to update aswell according to the new property value. However Vue JS doesn't work like that. You can fix this by adding a watcher.

In your LoginModal add this:

```
watch: {
    loginShow: function () {
        this.showModal= this.loginShow
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by [aBiscuit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5355875/abiscuit) it's better to add the new value in the watch handler like so:

```
loginShow: function (newVal) {
    this.showModal= newVal
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `nextValue` argument of watch handler, instead of referencing itself inside the handler. There are cases on my experience when this approach doesn't work as expected. Also, it makes handler behavior more readable and logical.

Comment: Isn't the use of watch is "too much" in the way that its always running in the back and listening to changes? and in this case the changes are not that often

Comment: Anyway, by doing this, the first click is ok but every second click is not. I mean that on the first time the newVal set to true and then set to false. This way the modal being display every second click

Comment: handle it by doing 
loginShow: function () {
    this.showModal= !this.showModal
}
Is it ok vue weise?

Comment: @Maayans I wouldn't say that using a watch is "too much", from my understanding Vue is pretty smart and (I think) will find the correct watchers to update once a value is changed. So the `watch` isn't constantly checking. As for the modal displaying every second click it's because of the code in your button. On click it sets `loginShow` to `!loginShow` which toggles it between true and false. And as for your last comment, I wouldn't suggest it that way. It may work but you are watching a property but you aren't using that property. I'd suggest either of the 2 ways displayed in my answer

Comment: @T.Dirks Thanks for the long comment! What do you mean "On click it sets loginShow to !loginShow which toggles it between true and false"? Don't I need to have this toggle? by removing this onclick event the modal doesn't showd.

Comment: @Maayans I'm affraid I misunderstood your second comment in that case. The button toggles the value of `loginShow` which also toggles the display of the modal. So every second click the modal will hide. Isn't this the desired functionality?

Comment: @T.Dirks hey, so no. the flow is first click->model opens. Click on the cancel or X button inside the modal -> modal close. second click -> the modal should open again.

Comment: @Maayans In that case I think you need to change the code of your button to `loginModalShow = true`, so that each time you click that button the modal should pop-up. However I don't know if this will work since you change hide the modal inside the component itself...

Comment: @T.Dirks ok, I guess I will do some tests. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Maayans No problem! But as for this Stack Overflow question, I think it's answered. It be great if you could select an answer as the accepted answer for future readers to find a solution better.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your child component using computed property:

```
<b-modal
  ref="LoginModal"
  v-model="showModal"
/>

export default {
  props:['loginShow'],
  computed: {
    showModal () {
      return this.loginShow
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this way, I get the warning - Computed property "showModal" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: Ahh... Yes. It's because you use showModal in v-modal.